# SQL: Output all names which belong to a category where all the countries within it are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table called Stores:

```
Name          |   Country   |   Category 
Pharmacy          Japan         Health
Green Vine        Italy         Dining
Red Palace        Morocco       Dining 
La Pizza          Italy         Dining 
Nature Shop       Japan         Health
Medical 100       Japan         Health
```

I want to write a query that outputs all the Names that belong to a category where all the countries are the same (e.g. all the stores in the Health category are in Japan). E.g. the output would be:

```
Name       |  Country  |  Category
Pharmacy      Japan       Health
Nature Shop   Japan       Health
Medical 100   Japan       Health
```

I know how to count the number of entries per category, but how can I tell whether all the countries within a category are the same? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.Country = t.Country AND 
                    t1.category = t.category AND
                    t1.Name <> t.Name
             );
```

Comment: What does SELECT 1 mean?

Comment: They are just flagging instances that meet the criteria since all they need to check for is existence.

Comment: @ceno980. . . `SELECT 1` means the existence of a row.

Comment: Would this solution work if I had to join two tables to get the table 'Store'? I am not sure how I can use this method if I have to join two tables called Shop and Info and then get all the names. E.g. I have the following code: select Shop.Name, Country, Category from Shop, Info where (Shop.Name=Info.Name). Adding the 'where exists' after I join the two tables does not work.

Comment: How does the 'where exists' work so that it knows that all the countries that belong to a category are the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with a `HAVING` clause, that checks that the minimum country is the same as the maximum country for a category, i.e. all countries are the same (if there cannot be `NULL`s, which seems to be the case). Then inner join these categories.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.category
                               FROM elbat t2
                               GROUP BY t2.category
                               HAVING max(t2.country) = min(t2.country)) x
                       ON x.category = t1.category;
```

Comment: What is 'x' in the above query?

Comment: @ceno980: An alias for the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to get all such categories for which all countries are same:

```
    Select t.category
    From table t
    Group by t.category
    Having count(distinct country)=1
```

Then you can use it to get StoreNames:

```
    Select t.name
    From table t
    Where t.category in
    ( Select t.category
    From table t
    Group by t.category
    Having count(distinct country)=1)
```

This syntax is compatible to MS  sql server, but I hope logic can be translated to mysql.

Comment: If I want to get all the categories for which all the countries are the same and are a specific country (e.g. get all the categories where all the countries are 'Morocco'), how could I do this? Would modifying the code so that the final line is: 'Having count(distinct country)=1 and country='Morocco' ) work?

Comment: For that you can use `Max(country)=Min(Country) and Max(country)='Morocco'` instead of `having` clause.